# $injector в AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Привет.
Помогите разобратся с данной функцией.

```
function simpleService(){
   this.name = "simpleService";
}

angular.module('foo', [])
   .service('simpleService', simpleService);

var myInjector = angular.injector(['foo']);
var service = myInjector.get('simpleService');

alert(service.name);
```

Насколько я понял эта штука получает сервисы со сторонего модуля.

Но в одном с проэктов я встретил следующее :

```
controller('MyCtrl2', ['$scope', '$injector', function($scope, $injector) {
            require(['controllers/myctrl2'], function(myctrl2) {
    // injector method takes an array of modules as the first argument

                $injector.invoke(myctrl2, this, {'$scope': $scope});
    }
    })
```

myctrl2.js

```
define([], function() {
    return ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        // You can access the scope of the controller from here
        $scope.welcomeMessage = 'hey this is myctrl2.js!';

        // because this has happened asynchroneusly we've missed
        // Angular's initial call to $apply after the controller has been loaded
        // hence we need to explicityly call it at the end of our Controller constructor
        $scope.$apply();
    }];
});
```

Что это за приемы?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var myInjector = angular.injector(['foo']);
> var service = myInjector.get('simpleService');
> ```

Это нестандартный способ получить провайдер. При помощи `$injector.get` можно получить разные виды провайдеры как *provider, service, constant, value, factory, decorator*, следующим образом:

```
angular.injector(arrayOfModulesToLoad).get(providerName)
```

В одном приложение вам вряд ли пригодится такой синтакс, так как angular сам занимается Dependency Injection, когда мы пишем:

```
angular.module('foo').controller('myController', function (simpleService) {
    // ...
}
```

Однако, `$injector.get` пригодится особенно если хотим получить провайдер вне приложения, напимер из js консоли браузера:

```
angular.element('body').injector().get('simpleService')
```